# How to add discord login to a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, discord

Im currently working on a chrome extension for my school project. This extension gets the url of the current active tab and sends to a discord channel. To do this how can I add discord login to my chrome extension?
Im using javascript and html to write the extension.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to either use [OAuth2](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2) or you could also use an [Webhook](https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/228383668-Intro-to-Webhooks) to directly send a message to a Channel over an request.

Comment: Is it possible to use OAuth2 with Javascript? Didnt find any info on that.

Comment: @SuvinNimnakaSukka For extensions specifically, you could take a look at [`chrome.identity` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity). But a Webhook approach would be _much_ easier.